# Problem splitting array when using group_concat

Tags: php, mysql

I am having problems exploding an array after using group_concat. When I explode the array into each part it works fine if I use -

```
group_concat(date,':',board,':',price separator ',') as loxxer
```

When I add a forth value like below, the foreach seems to stop just before the end and cuts off the last few values.

```
group_concat(date,':',board,':',price,':',departure separator ',') as loxxer
```

Here is the full code, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("    

SELECT *,   
group_concat(date,':',board,':',price,':',departure separator ',') as loxxer
FROM $tablename
GROUP BY brochure
")); 

foreach( $results as $result ):
echo $result->property;

// The bit I am having trouble with 
$dates = explode(',', $result->loxxer);     
foreach($dates as $datez) {     
echo $datez.'<br>';
}       

endforeach;
```

Here is the results with the last bit chopped off -

```
01/06/2020:All Inclusive:269.77:Gatwick
02/06/2020:All Inclusive:288.23:Gatwick
03/06/2020:All Inclusive:269.08:Gatwick
04/06/2020:All Inclusive:269.08:Gatwick
05/06/2020:All Inclusive:223.25:Gatwick
06/06/2020:All Inclusive:269.08:Gatwick
07/06/2020:All Inclusive:269.08:Gatwick
08/06/2020:All Inclusive:259.08:Gatwick
09/06/2020:All Inclusive:269.08:Gatwick
10/06/2020:All Inclusive:364.08:Gatwick
11/06/2020:All Inclusive:269.08:Gatwick
12/06/2020:All Inclusive:359.47:Gatwick
13/06/2020:All Inclusive:269.08:Gatwick
14/06/2020:All Inclusive:329.54:Gatwick
15/06/2020:All Inclusive:269.08:Gatwick
16/06/2020:All Inclusive:269.08:Gatwick
17/06/2020:All Inclusive:269.08:Gatwick
18/06/2020:All Inclusive:269.08:Gatwick
19/06/2020:All Inclusive:349.28:Gatwick
20/06/2020:All Inclusive:269.08:Gatwick
21/06/2020:All Inclusive:269.08:Gatwick
22/06/2020:All Inclusive:269.08:Gatwick
23/06/2020:All Inclusive:269.08:Gatwick
24/06/2020:All Inclusive:347.89:Gatwick
25/06/2020:All Inclusive:269.08:Gatwick
26/06/2020:All Inclusive
```

Comment: why this column has space in between *departure separator* ? if this is really your column name put `\`departure separator\`` like this

Comment: _“Here is the results with the last bit chopped off”_ - that does not appear to contain one single comma, anywhere. And yet, you are still trying to explode at a comma. How is that supposed to match?

Comment: column is called departure as separator is for the ','

Comment: The result above is after I have exploded at each comma

Answer (score 0):

Found problem  -max string length 1024.